# Multiple routes which uses the same uri

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible in laravel routes to set multiple routes for the same uri? example: /home based on if a user is guest or logged in or so on?

I tried some using filters but thoose just redirect around creating a loop, how would i if it's possible write my filters to support this?

I need this because the login page and logged in page should be at the same uri.

Comment: post the code of the filters. you have some logical error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know it there is a better solution, but I think you can do this:

```php
if(Auth::check()){
   Route::get('route-for-loggedin');
} else {
   Route::get('route-for-NOT-loggedin');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the controller.

`Route::get('login', 'AwesomeController@login');`

then in your controller

```
public function login()
{
    if ($user = Auth::user()) {
        return View::make('view', [ 'user' => $user ]);
    }

    return View::make('notLoggedInView');
}
```